# Передать номер порта на php-сервер

Tags: php

Для создания нескольких комнат я решил разграничить их по номеру порта. Для всех комнат установлен порт 8081, как перед созданием сокета передать на сервер номер порта?
Если записать на сервере `print_r($_POST);`
 то будет пустой массив

```js
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhr.open("POST", "serversocket.php", true);
 xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type',
 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
 xhr.send('8080');
 xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { // Ждём ответа от сервера
      if (xhr.readyState == 4) { // Ответ пришёл
        if(xhr.status == 200) { // Сервер вернул код 200 (что хорошо)
          alert(xhr.responseText); // Выводим ответ сервера
       }
      }
  }
```

UPD: 8080 здесь для примера

Comment: Это полная бессмыслица. Никакой номер порта для "комнат" не нужен. Тупо гет параметр с номером комнаты

Comment: Я думал об этом с самого начала. Но как сервер будет передавать данные в нужную комнату?

Comment: **точно так же**, сообщая в ответе номер комнаты

Comment: А, то есть на клиентской части нужно просто отсортировать нужный ответ по номеру комнаты указанному внутри?

Comment: Да, так это всегда и работает

Comment: Давным-давно посещала похожая мысль, когда в чат отправлялось сообщение с null. Спасибо что так быстро помогли, просто не передать сколько времени я сэкономил